# addClass and removeClass methods aren't working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, addclass, removeclass

I am planning to add and remove background-image to a specific DIV but it seems that it's not working well

jQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 340) {
   $("#navcontainer").addClass("bg2");
  } else {
   $("#navcontainer").addClass("bg1");
  }
 });
});
```

here is the css code :

```
#navcontainer{
height: 70px;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 9999;
}

.bg2{
background-image: url(bg2.png);
}
.bg1{
background-image:url(bg1.png);
}
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/addclass/ for more info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) accepts one or more classNames ***without the period***

```
$("#navcontainer").addClass("bg2");
```

It should be noted that jQuery has a [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) as well

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#navcontainer").toggleClass('bg2', $(this).scrollTop() > 340);
});
```

Comment: Thanks toggleClass really worked , but what's the difference between it and the addclass method

Comment: There's no difference, but as the name implies, it toggles the class, adding it if it's not there and removing it if is there. The reason it works here is because toggleClass takes a second argument, the `switch`, telling it to remove or add the class if you pass false/true, and your check for scrollTop returns exactly that, true or false.

Comment: aha thanks mate , so can i add a transition to this class ?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to write the classe name,  like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 340) {
   $("#navcontainer").addClass("bg2");
  } else {
   $("#navcontainer").removeClass("bg1");
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: not working either :(